# Python Requests 403 Error

Tags: python, django, file-upload, python-requests

I want to upload a file to a webserver for which I have written a simple client file like this.

client.py

```
import requests
def main():
    url_link = "http://localhost:8000/Home/UploadFile/"
    fileObj= open('VOI-0204.zip', 'rb')
    r=requests.post(url_link, files={'docfile': fileObj})
    print r.text
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The django url mapper is declared as follows:

urls.py

```
url(r'^Home/UploadFile/$', 'WebApp.views.uploadZip', name='uploadZip'),
```

Everytime I ran the client.py it is giving me a 403 error like this.

```
[29/Aug/2015 10:28:02] "POST /Home/UploadFile/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

But If I change the url_link in the client file like this

```
url_link = "http://localhost:8000/Home/UploadFile"
```

Now it is showing the Server Error [500] like this

```
[29/Aug/2015 10:33:32] "POST /Home/UploadFile HTTP/1.1" 500 63766
```

Any ideas??

Comment: There is no authentication set in there. For the very beginning I just want to see what are the inputs I am getting. But it is broken there and I can't even debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django expects a CSRF token on each POST request. Decorate your view by a `csrf_exempt` decorator in order to allow this script to run successfully. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt). Though I wouldn't suggest going down this path. CSRF tokens are for your protection.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def upload_zip(request):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the csrf token in your view, add {% csrf_token %} if you are using a form. 
If you need to do an ajax request, you need to implement some javascript code. 
Django official doc has some good articles about that, you can see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/